# getter of RealmList<T> not working, unable to accessa field using getter

Tags: android, json, realm

I am not able to access fields of a class using its getter because its actually a RealmList.

I have User class

```
public class User extends RealmObject  implements Parcelable{
    @SerializedName("userInfo")
    RealmList<UserInfo> userInfoList;

public RealmList<UserInfo> getUserInfoList() {
        return getUserInfoList;
    }

public void setUserInfoList(RealmList<UserInfo> getUserInfoList) {
        this.userInfoList = userInfoList;
    }
}
```

I have UserInfo class which has the fields I have to access and display on the view

```
public class UserInfo extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

  RealmList<UserInfo> userInfoList;
 public UserInfo(RealmList<UserInfo> userInfoList) {
        this.userInfoList = userInfoList;
    }

  @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I am not able to access "name" using userInfoList.getName(); in another class to display on the view

Comment: is it normal to return `getUserInfoList` in your function `getUserInfoList()` ?

Comment: and your setter looks wrong too

Comment: You probably shouldn't send RealmObjects through GSON. The RealmList tends to make it tricky.